# how to check if a sql statement is ready to be executed?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

How do I check if the statement can execute in my code? the second parameter won't be set if txtFirstName.getText() is empty.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Employees (id, firstName, lastName, adress, phone, email, photo, comments) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = database.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, database.users.size() + 1 + "");
            if (txtFirstName.getText().matches(""))
                statement.setString(2, txtFirstName.getText());
            statement.setString(3, txtLastName.getText());
            statement.setString(4, txtAdress.getText());
            statement.setString(5, txtPhone.getText());
            statement.setString(6, txtEmail.getText());
            statement.setString(7, txtPhotoURL.getText());
            statement.setString(8, txtComment.getText());

            statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Set your if-statement before the sql statement. And change it so that it will NOT execute if it is empty. You should also checkout the use of an autoincrement column. database.users.size()+1 will cause duplicates over time.

Comment: Use exception handler

Comment: Create a proper (check) constraint on the database, then handle any error the database server signals

Answer (score 0):

> the second parameter won't be set if txtFirstName.getText() is empty.

Yes, it will; it will be set to an empty string. Whether that's valid for this specific query and table structure is beyond the realm of JDBC.

You need to check your constraints in advance, separately, and then either make the call or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `else` condition to specify what to do if `txtFirstName` does not match the pattern, e.g.:

```
if (txtFirstName.getText().matches("")){
    statement.setString(2, txtFirstName.getText());
}else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name pattern");
}
```

This will prevent the code from executing errorneous `preparedstatement` and throw an `exception` with appropriate error message.